# Relational database tool, which can display PDF blobs

Tags: database, sqlite, pdf, libreoffice-base

I would like to collect my orders in a very simple relational database with some PDFs inside binary a field. I would like to easily browse the PDFs without building a frontend. There are many SQL admin tools available which are perfect for browsing the databases, but I have not found any free tools which could display the PDFs inside it or open them easily.

**Which existing free and platform independent tool is able to show PDFs in a database?**

For example:

- SqlLite Studio has a "Edit value" window, which can display the stored image.
- [SQLMastro](https://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/sqlite/maestro/help/06_05_04_blob_viewer_pdf/) is able to do it, but is not free.
- Images can also be shown in LibreOffice Base and Microsoft Access.
- In MS Access VBA it is possible to embed ActiveX applications or open a PDF stored at a path, but MS is not platform independent and VBA is very messy.

I would also be happy, if it would actually store a copy of the file temporary on the harddrive and automatically open it. I just want a single click solution.

I did not specify the actual database format, as I am happy to use any relation database which has such a tool already. I want to use some database instead of a *magical folder structure*.